# SyntaxError: non-default argument follow default argument when argument is a string

Tags: python, pandas

In my application, I have a main.py script that calls functions from other scripts. I am new working with functions in class and I think I am doing everything as found in the documentation but definitely, my code is not correct as I am getting this error.

```
# main.py
from clases.analysis import Analysis


file_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])

total_gene_affected = Analysis(cnv_mapped)
total_gene_affected = total_gene_affected.gene_affected_generator(file_name)


# analysis.py

class Analysis():
    def __init__ (self,cnvs):
        self.cnvs = cnvs
    def gene_affected_generator(self,cnvs=None, file_name)
        cnvs = self.cnvs
        
        # Some code here 
        # file_name is used at the end of the function
        pre_names.append(file_name + '_' + Name)
        return
```

The full error (sorry it must be a screenshot as I am woking in a cluster without internet)
[image]

I have been working all day with this and I don't know what I am doing wrong or what I am missing

Comment: As the error message states, the non-default argument `file_name` follows the default argument `cnvs=None`, which is not allowed. Default arguments must come after all non-default ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `filename` argument before the cnvs argument, i.e.

```py
# analysis.py

class Analysis():
    def __init__ (self,cnvs):
        self.cnvs = cnvs
    def gene_affected_generator(self, file_name, cnvs=None)
        cnvs = self.cnvs
        
        # Some code here 
        # file_name is used at the end of the function
        pre_names.append(file_name + '_' + Name)
        return
```